# Check if event has any listeners?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Is it possible to detect if event has any listeners? (I need to dispose my event provider object, if nobody needs it)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assume the class is in a 3rd party library and it can't be modified:

```
    public class Data
    {
       public event EventHandler OnSave;
       //other members
    }
```

In your program:

```
    Data d = new Data();
    d.OnSave += delegate { Console.WriteLine("event"); };
    var handler = typeof(Data).GetField("OnSave", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(d) as Delegate;

    if (handler == null)
    {
        //no subscribers
    }
    else
    {
        var subscribers = handler.GetInvocationList();
        //now you have the subscribers
    }
```

Comment: It seems calling GetInvocationList is not really necessary, checking handler for null is enough. Am I correct?

Comment: @user626528: yes you are correct. In this example I'm showing something that is possible useful in some cases.

Comment: If handler will be null when there are no OnSave events added, then the code above should have a null check or else would error.

Comment: This is even handy if you do have access to the library source, but your code is separated across solutions in different assemblies. Anyway have another Nice Answer badge.

Answer (score 11):

You can check if event is != null.

By the way, in C# you need this check each time you raise an event:

```
if (TheEvent != null) {
    TheEvent(this, e);
}
```

and the reason is exactly to check if the event has any listener.

**EDIT**
Since you can't access TheEvent from outside the class, you could implement a method that does the check:

```
public class TheClass {
    public bool HasEventListeners() {
        return TheEvent != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to check it outside the object, because it's made by the 3rd party. I need to check if somebody subscribes for object's event, and dispose it if there are no subscriptions.

Comment: I don't think you can, you need a method wrapper

Comment: Do you mean "Since you can't access..." in the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnSomethingEvent()); // false
    OnSomething += (o,e) => {};
    Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnSomethingEvent()); // true
}
EventHandler mOnSomething;

event EventHandler OnSomething {
    add { mOnSomething = (EventHandler)EventHandler.Combine(mOnSomething, value);   }
    remove { mOnSomething = (EventHandler)EventHandler.Remove(mOnSomething, value); }
}

public bool ContainsOnSomethingEvent() {
    return mOnSomething != null && mOnSomething.GetInvocationList().Length > 0;
}
```